Bluetooth connection with Android. Does device type matters?
I'm beginner on writing Android apps. I'm not sure about connectivity via Bluetooth. Does it mean with what device I try to connect? For example a Bluetooth scale. Is language API (I use Java) all I need to receive data from Bluetooth device or it depends on device?
Searched web but I haven't found something about that.

The specific details of how data gets exchanged between a Bluetooth-enabled scale and a phone may vary by scale, depending on whether or not there is an industry standard for Bluetooth-enabled scales. For example, there is an industry standard for heart rate monitors. Regardless, any programming language suitable for Android will be able to work with Android's Bluetooth APIs.

Just to add to @CommonsWare great comment: There is a Weight Scale Profile, but you need to check whether or not your scale implemented this profile.

You mean that data can be always collected, but the representation of data received could be complicated to understand?

Short answer is yes, technically all you need is an Android app written in Java and that the remote device also supports Bluetooth.
Long answer is that not all devices support Bluetooth. On Android, there's an API that you can use to check if your device supports Bluetooth:-

Checking if Bluetooth is supported

If your device supports Bluetooth and the remote device also supports Bluetooth, then yes the two can communicate. There are two main types of Bluetooth, namely Bluetooth classic which has existed since the inception of Bluetooth and was mainly used a cable replacement, and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) which was created/adopted around 2010. Most sensors (e.g. scales, thermometers, heart rates) are BLE devices and therefore the phone needs to talk to them over BLE.
Finally, even if both devices support Bluetooth, your Android app needs to understand how the data is formatted in order for your Android device to decode the Bluetooth packets that it receives over the air. For that there are mainly two types: 1) generic profiles that have been standardized by the Bluetooth group (i.e. if your Android app supports the adopted temperature sensor profile, it will be able to talk and understand any temperature sensor that supports this profile). The second type is custom profiles - this is when a company creates their own profile and usually their own app that understands that profile. Some companies publish this custom profile and therefore technically you can create an app that understands that profile, and some companies don't publish their customer profile which means your app will not be able to communicate easily with that device (unless you reverse engineer the profile).
Some useful links to get started:-

Android Bluetooth overview
Introduction to Bluetooth Low Energy
Bluetooth Low Energy: A primer
The ultimate guide to Android BLE development

